# Remap the alt key in Grub 2

Tags: grub, keyboard-layout

I have a problem with my keyboard: the left <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is not working any more.

When I logged in into the Window manager, I can remap the key to <kbd>caps lock</kbd>  key, and everything works fine.

I changed the password for my main user, but didn't take into account, that the encryption password for my home partition should be changed accordingly. So, I cannot log in.

I would like to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to log into shell, but that is not possible because I am missing <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

I have the root password, but I don't have USB booting drive. I also tried the on-site screen keyboard, but unfortunately on Ubuntu that one has no <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

How can I change the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key in Grub?

Comment: grub keyboard mapping has nothing to do with kernel's keyboard mapping.

Comment: _now I cannot log in_, what makes you think you can login from a console? Do you have access to the `root` account (whose "home" is `/root` and hopefully not encrypted)? Fastest way to me to recover the system, grab an USB keyboard with a working Alt key or just boot with a live distro.

Comment: Yes I have the root password. And here on holidays unfortunately I neither have a USB device nor an extra keyboard with me

Comment: You can try in single user mode from grub

Comment: Thanks @ctac_, this will help in my case: https://askubuntu.com/q/132965/34298

Answer (score 0):

You need two command-line based tools, [xev](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/xev.1.html) and [xmodmap](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/xmodmap.1.html).

You can use `xev` to remap a key, start the terminal window and run `xev`, then press the key whose behaviour you want to change. In your case the <kbd>alt</kbd> key. `xev` will show you information about the <kbd>alt</kbd> key. such as:

```
state 0x18, keycode 131 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 108
```

You can use `xmodmap` to swap two keys.

Comment: Nice answer. But that would only work if you can log on in the first place. I guess, you didn't read my question fully ;-)

Comment: @rubo77. Kindly, what is your system and the Grub version?

Comment: Ubuntu 18 with grub 2